# Android proximity sensor when uncoverd

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I work in project where i use proximity sensor my program should mute the phone when the proximity sensor is covered and restore it to normal when the sensor is uncovered. i managed to code for when the sensor is covered but i don't know the value for far when the sensor is uncovered i need a code to unmute when the sensor is uncovered.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

}
```

Comment: look into documentations 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html
and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: check this u ll get cm distance i hope whatever giv t a try http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/PROXIMITYSensor.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){

      if(event.values[0]<5){ audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_youwant);}else{ audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);}
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for mute/unmute

```
AudioManager   mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                int current_volume =mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                //If you want to player is mute ,then set_volume variable is zero.Otherwise you may supply some value.
                int set_volume=0;
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,set_volume, 0);
```